# Splitting lemma in the case the retraction is a crossed homomorphism

Tags: group-theory

Suppose we have an exact sequence of groups
$$1\rightarrow A\stackrel{i}{\rightarrow} B\stackrel{p}{\rightarrow} C\rightarrow 1$$
with $A$ abelian. Suppose also that we have an action of $C$ on $A$, whence an action of $B$ on $A$ (via $p$). I don't want to assume that this action is given by lifting elements of $C$ to $B$, then conjugating (well defined since $A$ is abelian), though it may well be this action.

Suppose further we have a surjective function
$$A\stackrel{r}{\leftarrow}B$$
with the property that $r\circ i = \text{id}_A$, and that $A\stackrel{r}{\leftarrow}B$ is a *crossed homomorphism*. This means, that for all $b_1,b_2\in B$, we have:
$$r(b_1b_2) = r(b_1)\cdot \,^{b_1}r(b_2)\qquad\text{for all $b_1,b_2\in B$}$$
(where the left exponent denotes the action of $b_1$ on $r(b_2)$).

Note that $r|_{i(A)}$ is just the inverse of $i$, hence a homomorphism.

I wish to know if given the above, $B$ admits some kind of splitting - e.g., is $B = A\times C$ (or perhaps a semidirect product, or something else?)

In general, the kernel of a crossed homomorphism (the preimage of 1) is a normal subgroup, and certainly $\ker(r)\cap i(A) = 1$.

It seems natural to wonder what one can say about $\ker(r)$. For example, must it surject onto $C$?

Is there a good general reference for algebra with crossed homomorphisms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not true in general that $\ker r$ is a normal subgroup of $r$, although it is a subgroup.

It is true that $\ker r$ surjects onto $C$. Since the action of $B$ on $A$ is defined using an action of $C$ on $A$ and the map $p$, it follows that $i(A)$ acts trivially on $A$.

So for $c \in C$, there exists $b \in B$ with $p(b)=c$. Let $r(b) = a$. Then

$$r(i(a^{-1})b) = ri(a^{-1})\,\, {}^{i(a^{-1})}r(b) = a^{-1}a=1,$$
and $p(i(a^{-1})b) = c$.

Comment: Ah, you're right it's not a normal subgroup. I made a mistaken in my calculation. I suppose this means it's a semidirect product?